Anybody have an Idea of what this pentagon is to on the 3d model
I just found this pentagon in this traffic cone hat I created anybody have a idea on what it is. Im making ugc for roblox. I think the pentagon is messing it up. can somebody atleast show me how to make the texture of the cone top-down to fit my photoshopped circle


To fix the cone texture, you'll need to do some UV unwrapping.  It makes it difficult to help you with this limited information; could you upload your file at https://blend-exchange.com/
